# around the world in eighty days - GMT vs Local Time

Tags: jules-verne

Why did not Phileas Fogg notice that his pocket watch ( set to London Time ) was behind the local time as he traveled eastwards?

Comment: Because he changed his watch to suit. Phileas wasn't unaware of time zones you know. He just forgot to account for the extra day he gains be travelling eastward.

Comment: For one thing, it would ruin the twist ending.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to a work in science fiction or fantasy genre.

Answer (score 14):

Fogg's watch was not set to London Time (he kept on changing it as he traveled). Passepartout’s watch was. However, it did not show the date in addition to the time.

This was described in chapter 37 (the last chapter). Fogg's error was an accident.

> How was it that a man so exact and fastidious could have made this
>   error of a day? How came he to think that he had arrived in London on
>   Saturday, the twenty-first day of December, when it was really Friday,
>   the twentieth, the seventy- ninth day only from his departure? The
>   cause of the error is very simple. Phileas Fogg had, without
>   suspecting it, gained one day on his journey, and this merely because
>   he had travelled constantly eastward; he would, on the contrary, have
>   lost a day had he gone in the opposite direction, that is, westward.
>   In journeying eastward he had gone towards the sun, and the days
>   therefore diminished for him as many times four minutes as he crossed
>   degrees in this direction. There are three hundred and sixty degrees
>   on the circumference of the earth; and these three hundred and sixty
>   degrees, multiplied by four minutes, gives precisely twenty-four
>   hours—that is, the day unconsciously gained. In other words, while
>   Phileas Fogg, going eastward, saw the sun pass the meridian eighty
>   times, his friends in London only saw it pass the meridian
>   seventy-nine times. This is why they awaited him at the Reform Club on
>   Saturday, and not Sunday, as Mr. Fogg thought. **And Passepartout’s
>   famous family watch, which had always kept London time, would have
>   betrayed this fact, if it had marked the days as well as the hours and the minutes!**

Comment: not really stated in the answer but if he presumes his watch to be inaccurate and need occational readjustment to be the correct time, it makes sense that he could not notice.

Comment: @anotherguest actually, it was the exact opposite. Fogg assumed his watch was perfect, and that other people's watches were off

Comment: The answer does not address the question - why he did not notice the discrepancy. Also you may want to add a spoiler warning at the top of the answer.

Comment: spoiler warning for a book over 100 years old? also, it says right there that Fogg forgot about the 4 minutes savings per degree around the planet.

Comment: @juvva - There was no discrepancy because he changed his watch's time according to the time zone. The extra day he gained is another matter entirely that he forgot to account for, and would not have normally noticed (unless he was taking sun measurements).

Comment: @juvva there was no discrepancy. During his travel, Fogg awoke/went to sleep 80 times, so he counted 80 days. Of course, he did not realize that each of those days was slightly shorter than his usual London day (given that his travel went through several latitudes, not a surprising thing to miss). Also, time zones in XIX century were way more complex than nowadays, with lots of local time (since there was no way to sinchronize clocks other than physically moving a clock from one location to the other, and that usually altered the clock accuracy).